# Open csv file delimited by pipe character "|" or not common delimiter

Tags: excel, vba, csv, delimiter

I'm trying to set up an Excel VBA code that opens up some .csv files and split into columns the information contained and delimited by the character `|`. I manage to open the file but the code I use opens my files without splitting the text according to the delimiter. So far I have tried the following code:

```
Sub OpenCSV()

Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
Dim sPath As String, sName As String

sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CSV_Files\"
sName = "Test.csv"

Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sPath & sName, Format:=6, Delimiter:="|")

End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725472/texttocolumns-function-uses-wrong-delimiter

Answer (score 4):

I remember this has driven me insane some time back.
It seems that Excel has an uncontrolled greed for `.csv` files. If you just change the ending (`.txt`, `.dat` or whatever), it will work!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I set up the extension change in VBA and now it works fine!

Comment: Did you just changed the ".csv" part of the string for ".txt" or do you created a new text file copying the content before open?

Comment: That would not make any difference (you might only screw up the encoding when you copy the content into a new file).

Comment: Exaclty. The only way I could get Workbooks.OpenText to work with a SemiColon delimited .csv was to use the Name method to temporarily change the filename to .txt, load the contents, then finally rename the file back to .csv.

Answer (score 2):

I tried doing this. It doesn't work. But if you try doing the same on a text file(by copy pasting the csv contents to a text file), it works.

If you look at [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx) , it specifically says that **'if it is a text file'** in the description of 'Delimiter' parameter of 'workbooks.open' method. Maybe this is the reason that it is not working.

I am not sure. This is a new thing for me too. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Rowan's solution actually does work.  The key is replace the file name "Test.csv" in his solution with "Test.txt" in your "\CSV_Files\" location. The "Test.txt" should not be a comma separate value type.  It should be a true TXT file type.

Check the file type in Windows Explorer.  Make sure it is not CSV.  If you use a CSV type you will be in fact telling Excel the data is parsed by a comma rather than the pipe delimiter.

If your workbook is in root:  c:\
Create the directory:  C:\CSV_Files
Put the text file:  Test.txt in the directory \CSV_Files

In your workbook open VBA and copy the full VBA code below.

The full VBA code should read:

```
Sub OpenCSV()

Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
Dim sPath As String, sName As String

sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CSV_Files\"
sName = "Test.txt"
 Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=sPath & sName, _
    Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
    xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False _
    , Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
Set wkbTemp = ActiveWorkbook

end sub
```

Close VBA and run the macro.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
Delimiter:= Chr(124)
```

Character 124 is the pipe "|"

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you.

```
Sub OpenCSV()

Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
Dim sPath As String, sName As String

sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CSV_Files\"
sName = "Test.csv"
 Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=sPath & sName, _
    Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
    xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False _
    , Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
Set wkbTemp = ActiveWorkbook

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Text2Excel()
Dim excel_app As Excel.Application
Dim max_col As Integer
Dim txtFromFile As Variant
Dim Sep As String

    'DoEvents

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    txtFromFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt),*.txt," & _
                                                "CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv")
    If txtFromFile = False Then
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' user cancelled, get out
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Sep = Application.InputBox("Enter a separator character." & vbNewLine & "For TAB Delimited keep BLANK.", Type:=2)

    If Sep = vbNullString Then
        ' user cancelled, get out
       Sep = vbTab
    End If

    'Pull the data from test file to activesheet

    Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=txtFromFile, DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, otherchar:=Sep, local:=True

    MsgBox "Data from selected file " & txtFromFile & " has been pulled to Excel.", vbInformation

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CSVtoXLS()
Dim xFd As FileDialog
Dim xSPath As String
Dim xCSVFile As String
Dim xWsheet As String
Dim xOtherChar As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.StatusBar = True
    xWsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFd.Title = "Select a folder:"
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
            xSPath = xFd.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Right(xSPath, 1) <> "\" Then xSPath = xSPath + "\"
    xCSVFile = Dir(xSPath & "*.csv")
    xOtherChar = InputBox("Please indicate delimiter:", "CSV file/Text to column Converter", ",")
    Do While xCSVFile <> ""
        Application.StatusBar = "Converting: " & xCSVFile
        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=xSPath & xCSVFile, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar:=";"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(xSPath & xCSVFile, ".csv", ".xls", vbTextCompare), xlWorkbookDefault
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Windows(xWsheet).Activate
        xCSVFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept on having problems with the Workbooks.Open's delimiter, on some CSV's it doesn't work properly.

So for these sheets I use this code:

Replace `sDelimiter` with your delimiter.

```
Dim sDelimiter as string: sDelimiter = "|"

Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelimiter
```

Disable `DisplayAlerts` if it keeps on prompting (disable DisplayAlerts before using `TextToColumns`)

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```